# AngularJS asynchronous function call

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, angular-promise

How to call a function asynchronously inside an Angular controller? I'v read about promises, but this in not a http call so i can't use that.
Is there any solution to resolve these kind of problems?
I would like to display a spiner/loader until the called function finishing it's job.

//Controller JS

```
   $scope.myFunctionCallOnClick = function()
   {
            if($scope.type=='TYPE1')
            {

               $scope.showSpiner();
              //This function has called syncronously, and i can't display my spiner
                Utils.doStuff(words,$scope);
                $scope.hideSpiner();
            }
            else
            {
                Utils.doStuff2(words,$scope);
            }
    }
```

//Utils.js - this is my helper factory

```
angular.module('app').factory('Utils', function() {
    var factory = {}; 
    ..
    .. 

    factory.doStuff = function()
    {
        var iteration = 10000000;
        whilte(iteration > 0)
        {
          console.log(iteration);
        }

    }
      ..
      ..
       return factory;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $timeout service to let the browser do some of its work (show your spinner in this case), and call doStuff from within the $timeout callback.

```
$scope.myFunctionCallOnClick = function () {
    if ($scope.type == 'TYPE1') {

        $scope.showSpiner();

        $timeout(function () {
            Utils.doStuff(words, $scope);

            $scope.hideSpiner();
        });

    }
    else {
        Utils.doStuff2(words, $scope);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use $timeout to call a function asynchronously

```
$timeout(function(){

      /// function logic    

}, 0);
```

similarly you can even use.. `$evalAsync`

read more about them [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2605-scope-evalasync-vs-timeout-in-angularjs.htm)